# Change select list function from "Remove" to "Add To"

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, optgroup

I have a script that generates an opt group select from a ul list and then replaces it. I would like to change the function to generate the select list but not replace the ul list. Here is the UL:

```
<ul id="sitemap">
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Small Business</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Workstations</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Workstations</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Printers</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Mobile Phones</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Public Sector</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">State Government</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Federal Government</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Support and Drivers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Large Enterprise</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Solutions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JS:

```
function sitemapCycle(){
    if(typeof(sitemapNode)==="undefined") sitemapNode= $("#sitemap");
    if($(this).find("ul").length)
    {
        sitemapNode= $(sitemapNode).append('<optgroup label="'+$(this).children().first().text()+'" />').children().last();
        $(this).find("ul li").each(sitemapCycle);
        sitemapNode= $(sitemapNode).parent();
    }
    else
    {
         $(sitemapNode).append('<option value="'+$(this).children().attr("href")+'">'+$(this).text()+'</option>');
    }
}

var sitemapNode;

$("#sitemap").removeAttr("id").after('<select id="sitemap" />').children().each(sitemapCycle).parent().remove();​
```

I'm not so experienced with js however I thought removing

```
var sitemapNode;

$("#sitemap").removeAttr("id").after('<select id="sitemap" />').children().each(sitemapCycle).parent().remove();​
```

would do the trick but it doesn't. Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/XvruF/

Answer (score 3):

Change the last line to:

```
$("#sitemap").removeAttr("id").after('<select id="sitemap" />').children().each(sitemapCycle);​
```

Comment: So it was `.parent().remove()`. Thanks for that.

Comment: Just note that it does move the id from the UL to the select item. The code logic uses that.

Comment: What if I wanted to keep the id on the UL as well?

Comment: It's not HTML standard to have two ids on the page with the same name. You can change the code a bit to use classes instead of ids.

Comment: Oh yes I'd forgotten about that. For my reference which part replaces the ids? Once I've changed the ids to classes I can then apply the change.

Comment: Two places: The line that starts with $("#sitemap") which identifies the UL by the id.  The second is the sidemapNode which identifies the select combo object defined by the id.  Here is code that changes both ids to classes: http://jsfiddle.net/jazaret/XvruF/3/ with that you don't need the removeAttr("id") line since there is no ids.

Comment: I just noticed that the select list doesn't show the selected value (it only shows the first value always). Would you know how I can change this please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I don't see a "selected" value on the sitemap in your code. If there is some attribute on the list item it can be asked at the time of building the select input to make that option selected.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When someone makes a selection from the select list e.g. "Services", the user is take to that page. But rather than showing "Services" it will still show the first select item which is "Home".. How can we get the script to show the selected page by default?

Comment: If you can change the list items on every page and put an attribute or class name for the "active" link then you can use that to set the value of the combo box as it loads. There are other ways to solve your issue but really would be difficult to fit into a comment box. Maybe try asking another question :)